# c++ bitset logical operations in O(log n)?

Tags: c++11, time-complexity, bitwise-operators, std-bitset

According to this post [Performance of doing bitwise operations on bitsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561579/performance-of-doing-bitwise-operations-on-bitsets) performance is `O(n)` how do I make it `O(log n)`.

Comment: I'd say it depends. You will have to provide more info. A O(1) solution for `std::bitset<8>` is entirely possible I think, but not for `std::bitset<2048>`.

Comment: You cannot do bitwise operation on bitsets of size O(n) in less than O(n) operations

Comment: Unless we have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, you cannot do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is you don't.

Assume you have a bitset of `n` size.
Let's look at the xor operator `^`.
It obviously has to look at each bit in both operands, so it makes `2n` lookups.
This results in a complexity of `O(n)`.

You can use assembler instructions that e.g. do it for 32 bits at a time, so the number of operations is `(n+31)/32`, but this doesn't change that the complexity is `O(n)`. After all complexity is calculated for `n` towards infinity and constant factors are disregarded.